# mmap vs sbrk, performance comparison

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, mmap, sbrk

Which of these calls is faster on average? I've heard that `mmap` is faster for smaller allocations but I haven't heard a comparison of either. Any information on performance for these would be nice.

Comment: You are aware that they do similar but different things ?

Comment: Yes I do. I just wanted to know if replacing one for the other in acceptable circumstances would lead to a performance difference.

Comment: Your mileage may vary. Best to measure against the exact environment you care about.

Comment: Note: if you call sbrk you will risk breaking  most malloc implmentations.  This has consequences.  For example, common C library calls [ like strdup() ], can be affected because they employ malloc().

Comment: Indeed, you definitely **cannot** use `sbrk` (or worse yet `brk`) in a program that might call `malloc`. And since any standard library function could call `malloc`, that means you cannot use the standard library, period.

Comment: I was writing a memory allocator so that isnt a problem since my allocator will be linked in place of malloc. I was just wondering about performance since it will be internally used for certain specific usages.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should tag this with a particular implementation (like `linux`) since the answer surely varies by implementation. For now I'll assume Linux since it's the most popular.

With that said, `brk` is in theory more optimizable, and in practice it runs about 10% faster on my machine. Allocating one page, these are the times I get:

- `brk`: min 2550 cycles, typical 2650 cycles
- `mmap`: min 2700 cycles, typical 2800 cycles

I remember hearing something along the lines of `brk` being able to skip locking the `mmap` semaphore, which would explain the discrepancy.

**Note:** I updated these times after adjusting my test to make a dummy calls prior to timing, to ensure that the code would all be in the cache.

Comment: oddly enough for me mmap was actually running faster than sbrk but then again with sbrk its possible to keep memory contiguous.

Comment: Perhaps your system's `sbrk` is performing some userspace locking or accounting, or even calling the `brk` syscall twice. (once to get the old `brk` and again to set the new one...?) If you're implementing `malloc` I would not rely on the system library's `sbrk` but make the `brk` syscall yourself.

Comment: I ended up using mmap as the primary way to grab memory from the system and use sbrk as a backup in case I get MAP_FAILED, I might try using the brk call instead to see what the performance of that would be.