# Emacs Buffer Allocation using mmap

Tags: linux, emacs, configuration, memory-management, memory-mapped-files

Why is `mmap` buffer allocation activated by default on cygwin, freebsd and irix6-5 but not on linux?

See `USE_MMAP_FOR_BUFFERS` in `emacs/src/config.h`.
and `use_mmap_for_buffers` in `emacs/configure.in`.

Isn't `mmap` based access ***superior*** to normal buffer allocation?

Comment: This question seems very specific. Perhaps you'll better post it to emacs-devel@gnu.org?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default glibc malloc() uses mmap for large allocations; From the malloc(3) manpage. "When allocating blocks of memory larger than  MMAP_THRESHOLD  bytes,  the  glibc
       malloc()  implementation  allocates  the  memory  as  a private anonymous mapping using mmap(2).
       MMAP_THRESHOLD is 128 kB by default, but is adjustable using mallopt(3)."

Perhaps switching to mmap on those other platforms is to work around poor malloc() implementations that don't do it themselves?

Comment: But how can malloc be a replacement for mmap? mmap maps file fd to memory but malloc just allocates memory not related to any file (descriptor).

Comment: @Nordlöw: See the "private anonymous mapping" part from what I quoted above. That is, the flags argument to mmap(2) is MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS. See the mmap(2) man page for more info.

Answer (score 2):

mmap() allocation is easier to realize in a threadsafe fashion, but brk() allocation is about 10% slower on Linux. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517601/mmap-vs-sbrk-performance-comparison).